# jssor: undocumented t3 d3 properties - how to

Tags: jssor

I found the t3 and d3 properties in the caption samples of jssor. how are these properties used? What are the possible values (i.e. 'B').

Are there other (undocumented) properties?

Tnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute 't' specifies transition for 'play in', 't2' is for 'play out'

't3' is for 'play out immediately'. 't' and 't3' are in the timeline of 'play in', but 't' is 'play in' to appear, 't3' is to 'play out' to disappear.

Attribute 'd' specifies time delay to animate in the timeline. 'd' affects 't', 'd3' affacts 't3'.

```
d:  a numeric value in milliseconds means delay of animation
du: a numeric value in milleseconds means duration of the animation
x:  a numeric value in ratio means the caption will fly horizontal by distance of
    parent container width
y:  a numeric value in ratio means the caption will fly vertical by distance of
    parent container width
z:  a numeric value in ratio means the caption will zoom by
r:  a numeric value means the caption will rotate by, 1 equas 360 degree.
f:  a numeric value (from 0 to 1) means the caption will fade by.
b:  a numeric value (in milliseconds) indicates an explicit begin time to start
    animation. By default, captions play in one by one. But if a caption specified
    with 'b' explicitly, it breaks the streamline.
Note: 'du', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'r' and 'f' can be percentage value, if a percentage value
is specified, the final behavior is a percent of original transition.
```

http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html