# JSSOR slider: Image Gallery demo add CSS rules for active mousedown event on desktop

Tags: css, jssor

For the demo that can be seen here [Image Gallery Demo](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html) I like to add CSS rules for when a user keeps the mouse button pressed down, so active mousedown event, on a thumbnail in the thumbnail gallery.

I would like to have the opacity of the active clicked thumbnail to be at 100% (what I managed to do) as well as have a white solid border or 2px round the thumbnail item. The border is what I am struggling with.

Thank you for your help.

```
.jssort07 .p:hover .i, .jssort07 .pav .i {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}    


/* thumbnail item mousedown active event for desktop behaviour */
/* .pdn since this is (mousedown) given the JSSOR docs */

.jssort07 .p:active .i, .jssort07 .pdn .i {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    /* how can I add CSS for a 2px white border for this event please */
    /* this below does not work */
    border: 2px solid white;                                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked already.

As 2px border added, please decrease the size of it as well,

```
.jssort07 .p:active .i, .jssort07 .pdn .i {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not working for me. I have created a private workbench with the image gallery demo, see your email for the link and access code, once we found the solution there I will post it here for all to see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So far I am purely developing the project in latest version of Chrome and Firefox for desktop and Android, have not even once loaded the site in IE. Why do you assume I am looking at the workbench in IE 11? The issue can be observed in Chrome as well as Firefox for desktop, just tried it. Besides I did for the first time just look at the project with IE 8 and Bootstrap, the Image Gallery and other things work fine. It is just the active mousedown white border that I have trouble figuring out really. Thank you for your continued support. Much appreciated still puzzled why it's not working.

Comment: For desktop, .jssort07 .p:hover works better than .jssort07 .p:active

Comment: Though :hover would not fire when the mousedown event occurs, right?. Let's take further discussion to email, OK? You got my email message and had a look at the workbench I assume?